# how to convert dictionary into object and save via sql database

Tags: c#, sql-server

In c# language using dictionary to store and that dictionary converted to object at finally that object stored to SQL server..

Comment: What have you tried?  Show the code how you are converting a `Dictionary` into an `object` this seems like an odd choice.

Comment: define "save via sql database"... as a single blob/clob? or into proper columns? define "object" - a well-defined DTO/POCO type? or something invented at runtime? or... well, a *dictionary* is an object, so "return inputDictionary;" would suffice...? or...?

Comment: What type are the things inside the Dictionary?

Comment: If you want an answer that is likely to be the one you need, you should ask a more detailed question defining what you want in as much detail as you can. There are a myriad of ways to interpret this question and I am disinclined to outline all the possibilities since, my comment has already taken more time and effort than seems justified. If you weren't new here I'd be inclined to vote for closure, as this is not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize it and save it as a json string. You could use http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json to serialize and deserialize you dictionary.

Comment: XML, Binary and Proto-buf serializations would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to convert the dictionary to an object that has the items of the dictionary as properties, you can use ExpandoObject:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Property", "foo" } };
var eo = new ExpandoObject();
var eoColl = (ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>)eo;

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    eoColl.Add(kvp);
}

dynamic eoDynamic = eo;

string value = eoDynamic.Property;
```

But I'm not sure how is doing that going to help you